# How to change and save color of body using dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

I'm attempting to change the body color using the options provided in a dropdown menu and saving those changes so when the user refreshes the page, the background color will be equal to what they set it as. However I'm having a problem in changing the background color according to the dropdown menu options.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn-secondmenu">Button</button>

<select name="colors" id="colors">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green" selected="selected">Green</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var select = document.getElementById("colors");

    select.onchange = function(){
        var selectedColor = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(selectedString);
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem('background') !== null) {
        getColour = localStorage.background;
        $('.bdy').css('background', getColour);
    } else {
        getColour = 'green';
    }

    $('.btn-secondmenu').click(function(){
        if(getColour == 'blue'){
            localStorage.removeItem('background');
            $('.bdy').css('background', 'red');
            localStorage.setItem('background', 'red');
        } else {
            getColour = 'blue';
            localStorage.removeItem('background');
            $('.bdy').css('background', 'blue');
            localStorage.setItem('background', 'blue');
        }
    });
});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's weird having a variable called `getColour`. That should normally be kept for getter functions which then return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple, easy to understand and complete working solution:

Your HTML with some better naming:

```
    <button id="changeColorButton" class="btn-secondmenu">Button</button>


    <select name="colors" id="changeColorSelect">
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green" selected="selected">Green</option>
            <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="black">Black</option>
    </select>
```

And jQ can be as short as this:

```
$('#changeColorButton').click(function() {
    var color = $('#changeColorSelect').val();
    $('body').css("background-color",color);
})
```

You can see it in action here: ( I could do a one-liner but harder to read).

[working JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uyywkeoq/)

Answer (score 1):

You are over complicating things here, you can achieve this in the `onchange` event of the dropdown, by getting the color with `$(this).val()` .

```
$('select[name="colors"]').change(function() {
  $('.bdy').css('background', $(this).val());
  localStorage.setItem('background', $(this).val());
});
```

**Note:**

There's no need to remove the item from the localStorage then reset it, only use `.setItem()` it will override the value of the item, if you check [**Storage.setItem()** MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) you can see that:

> The `setItem()` method of the Storage interface, when passed a key name and value, will **add** that key to the storage, **or update** that key's value if it already exists.

**Demo:**

```js
$('select[name="colors"]').change(function() {
  $('.bdy').css('background', $(this).val());
  //localStorage.setItem('background', $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bdy">
  <select name="colors" id="colors">
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="green" selected="selected">Green</option>
                <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                <option value="black">Black</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason your code isn't working on JSFiddle or my website. It looks like a good solution though and it might be the only one that actually saves the color change.

Comment: @SterlingKing can you please provide a link to the Demo/fiddle?

Comment: Ok the colour change worked now, it's not saving the colour when I refresh however. Maybe it's due to the code being hosted on fiddle rather than my own web host? https://jsfiddle.net/zwmy23qc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$('.bdy').css('background-color', getColour);
```

If that is `body` tag then better to use:

```
$('body').css('background-color', getColour);
```